# QTreeWidget drag and drop only when pressing key

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt5

So, let's consider this little snippet:

```
import sys
import random
import string

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu, QAction, \
    QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor, QKeySequence


class PageTree(QTreeWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        self.index = 0
        self.header().hide()
        self.view_menu = QMenu(self)
        self.create_actions()
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

    def create_actions(self):
        action = QtWidgets.QAction("Add new", self.view_menu)
        action.triggered.connect(self.on_add_page)
        action.setShortcuts(QKeySequence("a"))
        self.view_menu.addAction(action)
        self.addActions(self.view_menu.actions())

    def add_page(self, name, parent=None):
        if (parent is None and len(self.selectedItems()) == 1):
            parent = self.selectedItems()[0]

        item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
        item.setText(0, name)
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        self.addTopLevelItem(item)

        if (parent):
            parent.setExpanded(True)

        return item

    def on_add_page(self):
        self.add_page("test_page_{0}".format(self.alphabet[self.index]), None)
        self.index += 1
        self.index %= len(self.alphabet)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, ce):
        super().contextMenuEvent(ce)
        self.view_menu.exec(QCursor.pos())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tree_widget = PageTree()
    tree_widget.resize(400, 600)
    tree_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, the current code shows a simple QTreeWidget that allows you to reorder items using drag and drop builtin functionality thanks to `setDragEnabled, setDragDropMode, setSelectionBehavior` function.

Here's the thing, I'd like to implement a behaviour where the drag and drop happened only when pressing a key (ie: ctrl). Otherwise I'd like the widget to behave normally and the items remaining static no matter if you're trying to drag items nor holding the mouse button while hovering items.

How could I implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy to implement by overriding `startDrag`:

```
class PageTree(QTreeWidget):
    ...

    def startDrag(self, actions):
        if QtWidgets.qApp.keyboardModifiers() & Qt.MetaModifier:
            super().startDrag(actions)
```

Note that I've used the Meta (Windows) key here, because the [Ctrl and Shift modifiers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum) affect various aspects of selection in combination with the mouse. (Also, on Linux, the Alt + drag combination is normally used to move windows around, so it may not be a good choice either). However, you might be able to work around this issue by choosing a different [selection mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum).

Comment: Wow, that was easy indeed :) . Still, I don't get what's the problem on using the control key, i've tried and it works alright... am i missing something?

Comment: @BPL. For me, using the control key can conflict with the selection. If an item is *not* selected, ctrl+drag works fine. But if it *is* selected, the initial ctrl+click deselects the item, and the drag fails. I suppose it must be platform-specific thing.

Comment: When I'd asked this question a long time ago I didn't know what you meant by control key conflicting selection and didn't insist about it (i thought it was working ok) but today I've tried using some of my old widgets and I've finally [understood](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r1eoun9ji2uxq3k/2018-08-04_15-44-15.gif). I'm trying to find a proper solution to it and still being able to use control modifier (window meta key will popup the windows start menu) but haven't found anything yet. Any suggestion so far?

Comment: @BPL. You can't have it both ways, so you'll have to either switch off extended selection or choose a non-conflicting mouse+key combination.